# Spring ConditionalOnProperty cannot read property in custom.properties file

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, properties-file

Hi I have some custom properties files like application.properties.And I put some property in this files.Myproblem is @ConditionalOnProperty cannot read myproperties in customproperties file.
If I put same property in application.properties ConditionalOnProperty works but when I put myproperty in customproperties file that time it is not working.Except ConditionalOnProperty I dont have any problem to read values from custom properties file.Is there any way to read external properties from ConditionalOnProperty in spring boot.

```
@Congiuration
@PropertySource("classpath:myproperties.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="mycustomprop")
public class MyProperties{
private String myproperty;


@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "mycustomprop.myproperty", havingValue = "false") //not work when myproperty in customproperty file
public class MyConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer



@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource("classpath:myproperties.properties")
})

public class MyApplication
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `@PropertySource annotation` needs to go on a `@Configuration` class (or @SpringBootApplication if you want), not your custom MyProperties object.

Comment: I tried it boot component or configuration and I also put @PropertSource to springbootapplication but not changed...

Comment: post the complete code you tried with having @propertysource on your configuration.

Comment: I dont understand these are my code I tried.MyProperties this is custom properties file.And it has a property myproperty.I want to use @ConditionalOnProperty annatotion but it cant read this property